# Don't stop executing a function when called with -h

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argument-passing, argparse

My main python functions accepts `argv` and calls two other functions with these arguments to set up the whole application.

The issue is that if `argv` includes `-h` (`--help) then it is passed to the first function, it prints it's usage message (generated by argparse) as expected, like below:

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  -x section
```

**but then execution is stopped!**, and we are back at the prompt.

I would like the execution to continue so the second function is also called, and its usage message also gets printed. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: Take a look at the argparse module. http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

Comment: @Pogo: He *is* using the argparse module, that's what is raising the system exit when `-h` is passed in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to catch the `SystemExit` exception:

```
exited = None
try:
     function1(argv)
except SystemExit as e:
     # don't exit just yet
     exited = e
function2(argv)

# If function 2 *did not* exit, there was a legitimate reason
# re-raise the SystemExit exception
if exited is not None:
    raise exited
```

Note that I *store* the system exit exception raised in `function1`; it could be that it was raised as a result of a different action, not the `-h` flag. If `function2` doesn't raise an exception itself, we re-raise the original `SystemExit` exception to clean up properly.

The `except SystemExit as e:` statement captures the exception in a local variable `e`. The local variable thus assigned is normally deleted at the end of the `except` block (to prevent a reference cycle); if you want to use that exception outside of the `except` suite you need to store it in a *new* variable; this is why `exited` is a separate variable defined outside of the `except` suite.

Alternatively, you can opt to remove the `-h` switch from the `function1` argparser altogether by using the `add_help=False` option, then handling help manually there.

Comment: thanks for the help. I appreciate both the provided solution. I choose to move the usage from the first function to the second function and turn-off the usage in the first function. Then only one function is printing its usage (I am thinking this is clearer from user´s perspective)

Answer (score 4):

The default implementation of the help command provided by argparse displays a help message and exits. You'll need to prevent this from being added, and define your own custom argument that displays help without exiting instead.

First, use the [`add_help=False`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#add-help) keyword parameter when creating the parser to prevent the default implementation from being added. Then add your own argument normally, and when it occurs, call [`parser.print_help()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.print_help) to display the help message.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument('-h','--help', action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args(argv)
if args.help:
    parser.print_help()
```